# Is the secondary index feature of cassandra deprecated? paging with secondary index

Tags: cassandra

Or is it used from time to time and enhanced?

As paging is a big issue of Cassandra. I have a strategy to page using secondary index:
      Add a column "page_number" corresponding to each column you want to sort and page, create an index on the "page_number" column or just use it as the clustering column. The "page_number" is a good candidate for indexing, since it has low cardinality: every entry in the same page has the same page number. If there are 100 entries in one page, then there are 100 entries with the same page number. Thus is low cardinality. We can order the entries according to each column and set the corresponding "page_number". You can retrieve one page and do the corresponding sorting and send to display. Is this a good way or not?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a case of deprecation but secondary indexes can lead to bottlenecks, there's actually a ticket on C*'s JIRA to build global indexing to supersede the per-node secondary indexes. There are certain patterns that allow devs to avoid using secondary indexes (one basic example being building a compound PK rather than a PK and a secondary index).

There's a blog that [digs deep into secondary indexes](http://www.wentnet.com/blog/?p=77) and when they are useful, I'd advise you to take a look.